# TSQL - Getting all results between month/year range

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure that accepts the following parameters:

1. Month From
2. Year From
3. Month To
4. Year To

Right now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT      COL1, MyDate
FROM        [dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE       MONTH([MyDate]) >= @fromMonth
AND         MONTH([MyDate]) <= @toMonth
AND         YEAR([MyDate])  >= @fromYear
AND         YEAR([MyDate])  <= @toYear
GROUP BY    COL1, MyDate
```

But If I run the query with the parameters:

1. Month From = 9
2. Year From = 2016
3. Month To = 3
4. Year To = 2017

I get no results even if i have results that should be returned.

Comment: Woah woah that is messy.   Please look at the TSQL documentation on their extensions. You're making your life harder than it is because there are commands that easily does it .

Comment: You need to do criteria based on the date as a whole. Look at your month criteria. The month in your data has to be greater than nine and less then three. What number do you know that is higher then 9 and lower than 3?

Comment: Can you provide your schema and sample data?
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sql server version 2012+, you can use [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) and [`EOMONTH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx):

```
DECLARE @FromDate datetime, @ToDate datetime

SELECT  @FromDate = DATEFROMPARTS(@fromYear, @FromMonth, 1),
        @ToDate =  EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@ToYear, @ToMonth, 1)),

SELECT      COL1, MyDate
FROM        [dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE       [MyDate] >= @FromDate
AND         [MyDate] <= @ToDate
GROUP BY    COL1, MyDate
```

For versions before 2012, you can constract the date with a little math and casting:

```
DECLARE @FromDate datetime, @ToDate datetime
SELECT  @FromDate = CAST(CAST(@FromYear * 10000 + @FromMonth * 100 + 1 as char(8)) as date),
        @ToDate =  DATEADD(MONTH, cast(CAST(@ToYear * 10000 + @ToMonth * 100 + 1 as char(8)) as date))
SELECT      COL1, MyDate
FROM        [dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE       [MyDate] >= @FromDate
AND         [MyDate] < @ToDate
GROUP BY    COL1, MyDate
```

Note the use of `DateAdd` to get the first day of the month after the `@ToDate` and using `<` and not `<=`.

Comment: You will need to include logic to work out what the last day of the ToMonth is, otherwise you won't get the whole of the month in the results. Alternatively you could work out when the next month is and change the criteria to < ToDate.

Comment: @ChrisFlynn EOMONTH does that for you.

Comment: That's awesome, I did not know that!

Comment: @Kendo - It's worth noting that this makes the `WHERE` clause [SARGABLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) so that it can benefit from indexes. Since you didn't include the schema, we can only guess at the data type of `MyDate`. If it includes a time, e.g. a `DATETIME`, then your `GROUP BY` should probably include a `CAST` to `DATE`.

Comment: Thanks zohar. Unfortunately I'm limited to SQL server 2008 r2. Sorry I definitely should have put that in the question

Comment: I've edited my answer with a select for lower versions. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you didn't give us some sample data from your table, I generated my own.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
      MyCol VARCHAR(10)
    , MyDate DATETIME
    );
INSERT  INTO #Temp
        ( MyCol, MyDate )
VALUES  ( 'A', GETDATE() ),
        ( 'A', '2016-09-01' ),
        ( 'B', '2016-09-03' ),
        ( 'B', '2016-08-28' ),
        ( 'A', '2017-03-01' ),
        ( 'A', '2017-04-01' );
```

Let's take one date (`2016-09-01`) and break it down.

Your `WHERE` clause is effectively testing the following conditions for the first row.

1. `9 >= 9` => True
2. `9 <= 3` => False
3. `2016 >= 2016` => True
4. `2016  <= 2017` => True

Because you're `AND`-ing all of these conditions, you're not returning the results you're wanting.

You need to evaluate your values as dates rather than numbers, otherwise you'll encounter these issues.

You could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @ToDate AS DATE = CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR, @toYear) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @toMonth) + '-1');
DECLARE @FromDate AS DATE = CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR, @fromYear) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @fromMonth) + '-1');

SELECT  t.MyCol
      , t.MyDate
FROM    #Temp AS t
WHERE   t.MyDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
GROUP BY t.MyCol
      , t.MyDate;
```

This is a good starting point, but given your provided variables, you'll only get data from `2016-09-01` to `2017-04-01` rather than `2016-09-01` to `2017-03-31`.

So you'll need to add an additional month. You can do this a variety of ways (Add one to the month and check to see if it's over 13, `DATEADD`, etc.)

I chose [`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) because it's a little simpler.

Your end result comes up like this:

```
DECLARE @ToDate AS DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR, @toYear) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @toMonth) + '-1'));
DECLARE @FromDate AS DATE = CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR, @fromYear) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @fromMonth) + '-1');

SELECT  t.MyCol
      , t.MyDate
FROM    #Temp AS t
WHERE   t.MyDate >= @FromDate AND
        t.MyDate < @ToDate
GROUP BY t.MyCol
      , t.MyDate;
```

Edit: There's probably a cleaner way to generate a date than doing concatenation and converting.